# Display/Update Breadcrumb when using ASp.Net MVC MVCSiteMapProvider with AngularJS Routing (SPA)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am building an app built using ASP.Net MVC and AngularJS.  I use [MVCSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Advanced-Node-Visibility-with-ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider)  for building the site map and building Breadcrumb. I use Hybrid-SPA approach where part of the routing is handled by MVC and part by AngularJS.  Switching between each module is handled by MVC and navigating with in the Module is handled by AngularJS (Similar to but with some modifications http://www.codemag.com/article/1605081).

My problem is with the Breadcrumb.
1) When I reload the page when in a route that is handled by Angular, the Breadcrumb is not built since the URL is not handled by MVC.
2) Is it possible to update the breadcrumb with the inner pages links when navigating through SPA handled by AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of MVCSiteMapProvider and I use ng-breadcrumb (https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb)

Since you should always have a route defined at the angular level but the info at the MVC level is incomplete this is the only way to handle a complete breadcrumb.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, I was thinking of using ng-breadcrumb. But removing MVCSiteMapProvider will remove the Menu hierarchy as well.

Comment: You don't have to remove it if you are using it for the menu, just don't use it for the breadcrumbs. Combining MVC and Angular is kind of an art form at this point, sometimes you will have overlapping capability.